# cURL error 60 when Installing WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu, ssl, curl

I am getting a error when installing a WordPress plugin.

> Download failed. cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

I've tried to modify the php.ini file by adding a cacert.pem to

> curl.cainfo = /path/cacert.pem

I'm running WordPress on an Ubuntu server with apache2 and PHP 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this to work! I had this issue for hours, because i was editing the wrong php.ini from other answers here on stackoverflow.

here's what i did

Download the [certificate bundle.](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html)

Put it inside of `C:\wamp64\bin\php\your php version\extras\ssl`

Make sure the file `mod_ssl.so` is inside of `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache(version)\modules`

Enable `mod_ssl` in `httpd.conf` inside of Apache directory `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.27\conf`

Enable `php_openssl.dll` in `php.ini`. Be aware my problem was that I had two php.ini files and I need to do this in both of them. One is the one you get from your WAMP taskbar icon here.

[image]

and the other one is located in `C:\wamp64\bin\php\php(Version)`

find the location for both of the `php.ini` find the line where it says `curl.cainfo =` and give it a path like this

`curl.cainfo = "C:\wamp64\bin\php\php(Version)\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"`

Now restart your server and you should be good to go